# How to print all the year separately leap year and non leap year?

Tags: python

which module will help us in finding the leap and non-leap year between certain dates and year?

I tried using python but found some syntax error; I was unable to find the error.

Comment: Well, if you don't show the code and the error it would be very difficult to help you

Answer (score 1):

There's a module called [**calendar**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) in python

You can use is as the following

```
import calendar
year = 2021
print("Is the year: {} a leap year: {}".format(year,calendar.isleap(year)))
```

Output:
`Is the year: 2021 a leap year: False`

The `isleap(year)` method will return boolean as True or False.

Answer (score 0):

try this function :

```
from datetime import date

def find_leap_years(start_date, end_date):
  leap_years = []
  non_leap_years = []
  for year in range(start_date.year, end_date.year+1):
    if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0:
      leap_years.append(year)
    else
       non_leap_years.append(year)
  return {leap_years,non_leap_years}
```